# Window Service status it is appearing as running, But not executing the method in c#

Tags: c#, service, window

refer to below code:

`ChangeResumeformat()` is a method which I want to execute on the time basic, but this is not picking up.
On the debug case I can easily the execute the method and get the result.
Please help.

```
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    { 
        WriteToFile("started open " + DateTime.Now);
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ChangeResumeformat);
        timer.Interval = 100000; //number in milisecinds
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        //   ChangeResumeformat()
    }
     public void ChangeResumeformat(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Where did you make timer? how exactly are you debugging it

Comment: I have added my method below InitializeComponent();

Comment: there is still no code making the timer...

Comment: timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ChangeResumeformat);
        timer.Interval = 100000; //number in milisecinds
        timer.Enabled = true;

Comment: no that assigns the event, timer is not made then

Answer (score 0):

so your saying when 100000 miliseconds pass your service isn't calling "ChangeResumeformat" method? set interval first and set it 10000 thats 10 seconds and start service.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    { 
        WriteToFile("started open " + DateTime.Now);
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        timer.Interval = 10000; //number in milisecinds
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ChangeResumeformat);
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

P.S. does this work WriteToFile("started open " + DateTime.Now); when u start service? it might not have permission to writetofile and run into exception.

you can check event viewer for detailed logs

Comment: File creating I am able to write in the file

Comment: are you creating instance of timer? System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an instance of Timer first and then reference it in OnStart()

Create a Timer object as a member of the class (using System.Timers):

```
private Timer timer;
```

Initialize timer in your OnStart method

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{ 
    timer = new Timer();
    WriteToFile("started open " + DateTime.Now);
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    timer.Interval = 100000; //number in milisecinds
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ChangeResumeformat);
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```